# React with typescript types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

If I use react with typescript (tsx) like this:

```
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";

export function MyCounter({ count, onCountChange }: { count: number; onCountChange: Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>> }) {
    return (
        <>
            <p>Count: {count}</p>
            <button onClick={() => onCountChange(count + 1)}>Increment</button>
            <button onClick={() => onCountChange(count - 1)}>Decrement</button>
        </>
    );
}
```

Is there a way to simplyfy the type for the props? Or is ther a best practice how to do it?

Is it a good idea to hava a custom type like this?:

```
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";

export type MyCounterProps = {
    count: number;
    onCountChange: Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>;
};

export function MyCounter({ count, onCountChange }: MyCounterProps) {
    return (
        <>
            <p>Count: {count}</p>
            <button onClick={() => onCountChange(count + 1)}>Increment</button>
            <button onClick={() => onCountChange(count - 1)}>Decrement</button>
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I usually do it:

```
import {FC} from "react"
//Define a interface for this component
interface IProps {
    count: number;
    onCountChange: Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>;
};
//Assign it as FunctionalComponent type with IProps interface
export function MyCounter:FC<IProps>({ count, onCountChange }) {
```

It is much cleaner to define type or interface props and then assign it to the functional component itself.